# ¿Porque mis carpetas no se sincronizan usando virtualbox?

Tags: laravel, virtualbox, homestead

Estoy desarrollando en laravel con homestead y este es mi archivo Homestead.yaml:

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 2
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: ~/code/gestor-reportes
      to: /home/vagrant/code/gestor-reportes

sites:
    - map: gestor.test
      to: /home/vagrant/code/gestor-reportes/public

databases:
    - gestor

features:
    - mariadb: false
    - ohmyzsh: false
    - webdriver: false

# ports:
#     - send: 50000
#       to: 5000
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

Al momento de entrar a la maquina virtual con **vagrant ssh** y crear el proyecto con **laravel new gestor-reportes** el proyecto se crea con exito y sin ningun problema pero por algun motivo no me aparece ningun directorio en mi maquina local osea en **~/code**

Comment: Al momento de correr vagrant up dentro de una de las linea de la termina me dice que hubo un problema al montar alguno de mis directorios.

Comment: los que hice fue cambiar map: ~/code/gestor-reportes por map: ~/code y to: /home/vagrant/code/gestor-reportes por to: /home/vagrant/code sin embargo esto se considera mala practida dentro de la documentacion de laravel entonces a pesar de que sincroniza todos los archivos esta respuesta no es una solucion.

Comment: se considera mala practica ya que se tiene que mapear los proyecto individualmente y no toda la carpeta como hice en la repuesta anterior ya que esto hace que el rendimiento sea mas lento.